# The right way of inserting HTML in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, contenteditable, quill

I have a custom text editor and I want to give users an ability to insert a math formula. I am writing in polymer 2.0 and use [this element](https://github.com/janmarthedal/math-tex) to display laTex formula. I tried `document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<math-tex>\int_a^b</math-tex>');` and it works but it appends an html in a 'new line'. Then I tried

```
 const pNodes = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("p")
    const lastP = pNodes[pNodes.length - 1]

    let span = document.createElement("span")
    span.innerHTML = "<math-tex>_a^b</math-tex>"

    lastP.appendChild(span)
```

It insert formula inline but and can't move caret beyond inserted formula. It just sticks to the last text and doesn't move on. To be clear I want to replicate the behavior of [quill editor's](https://quilljs.com/) inline formulas